# RegEx that match react router path declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a map of routes with react router path as keys, eg:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    page: "mySettings",
    label: "pages.mySettings",
    path: "/professionels/mes-reglages.html",
    exact: true
  },
  {
    page: "viewUser",
    label: "pages.viewUser",
    path: "/users/:id/view.html",
    exact: true
  }
];
```

I want from a location retrieved with `useHistory().location.pathname`, to match all the path that match the key in react-router terms, eg:

- `(pathname) => get(routesMap, "/professionels/mes-reglages.html")` => should match `routesMap.get('/professionels/mes-reglages.html')`
- `(pathname) => get(routesMap, "/users/11/view.html")` => should match `routesMap.get('/users/:id/view.html')`

and all react-router paths so this should work too:

- `(pathname) => get(routesMap, "/users/11/settings/10/items/24/view.html")` => should match `routesMap.get('/users/:userId/settings/:settingId/items/:id/view.html')`

I have started here, any idea how I can do that with a regexp?

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wing-fjgm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments i adjusted the code a bit and wrote a rapper function for your lookup.
The following rules you have to watch out for when creating the urls:

- The last id always gets replaced by {id}
- All other ids get replaced by url part to id without plural and "Id" attached ("/users/111" -> "/users/{userId}")

This would be the function:

```js
const getRouteFromPath = (map, url) => {
  if (url.match(/\/\d+\//g).length > 1) {
    let allowedUrlPart = getAllowedIdQualifier(map);
    let urlParts = url.match(/(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/\d+\/)/g);
    urlParts.forEach(val => {
      if (!allowedUrlPart.includes(val)) {
        urlParts = urlParts.slice(urlParts.indexOf(val), 1);
      }
    });
    urlParts.forEach((val, key, arr) => {
      if (key === arr.length - 1) {
        let regex = new RegExp("(?<=/" + val + "/)\\d+", "g");
        let replacement = ":id";
        url = url.replace(regex, replacement);
      } else {
        let regex = new RegExp("(?<=/" + val + "/)\\d+", "g");
        let replacement = ":" + val.slice(0, -1) + "Id";
        url = url.replace(regex, replacement);
      }
    });
    return map.get(url);
  } else {
    url = url.replace(/\/\d+\//g, "/:id/");
    return map.get(url);
  }
};

const getAllowedIdQualifier = map => {
  let allowedQualifiers = [];
  map.forEach(val => {
    let allowed = val.path.match(/(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/:)/g);
    allowed.forEach(e => {
      if (!allowedQualifiers.includes(e)) {
        allowedQualifiers.push(e);
      }
    });
  });
  return allowedQualifiers;
};

export default getRouteFromPath;
```

As parameter you pass in the url to match as first parameter and the map of routes as the second paramter and call the function getRoute() instead of the direct map.get() call you where using before.

Here is the example with the urls adjusted to follow the rules, since you need some rules to be able to apply RegEx.

**EDIT:**

I adjusted the script, so that it reads the map first and determines the allowed paths which accept a id and then check the possible ids from an actual url against it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-moon-9oyj9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: That coule work in manu place but general the last one is just `{id}` miles `/users/10` => `/users/{id}`

Comment: How can I wrap the initial map object in order to keep the map attributes but allow more path such as computed url to be used for getting within the map ?

Comment: Also,  the way you replace for you to declare all the entities.  It would be better if you could do it automatically by detecting the registered placeholders and compute this solution

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa adjusted my answer based on your comments

Comment: This is exeptionnal thanks. I will gladly use that code. How can you be more permissive: (1) allow N digits (2) allow the last id to be id or userId => `/users/{userId}`  => `getRoute('/users/122', map)` in case a developer forgot about that rules, not to break the app exepectively, it should first check for id, then if it does not find it, check for `userId` ? Thanks a lot this is gold!

Comment: The length is pretty easy to adjust you. You just have to search for the {1, 3} which says match ids from 1 to 3 digits you can adjust this to make it "infinte" long just replace teh curlybrackets with a +.

Comment: I had to look deeper into that because at the moment when there is just one id it gets replaced by {id}, respectivly the last one when there is more. You would have to implement a callback and check if a valid result was returned and when not change the replacement. I think it would be better to adress the developer to take a look at the rules. But if you want i can take another look when i have time to implement a callback

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this bring some sort of restriction ? Such as not being allowed to create url that include numbers? For example `/users/{userId}/books/2019/galleries/{galleryId}/item/{id}`  or `/users/{userId}/2019/08/12/galleries/{galleryId}/item/{id}` ? How can this turn bullet proof for real use case?

Comment: With your permission, I'd like to use it in https://yeutech-lab.github.io/react-router-dom-utils/#Link , this way, I will be able to fetch the page on mouse over because I will be able to find the pages from the final url

Comment: At the moment the use of numbers inside the url would cause some problems, but i will take a look and i hope i can provide you an answer shortly how to allow them.

Comment: Yes you have my permission to use it anywhere.

Comment: I did a mistake, react-router does not expect url such as `/users/{id}`, it expect `/users/:id`, could you update accordingly please ? I take note and thanks a lot for sharing this work. I haven't found a framework that handles those efficently, while everyone knows hard coded path are not the way to go for large app. Thanks again for sharing this!

Comment: I have created a codesandbox with the fix `:id` => https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-cori-ufnpv It seems to work fine but it is not bullet proof with number, I am looking forward to get the version that allow that. Thanks a lot again

Comment: No clue if that help https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regex

Comment: I just updated the answer once more. Now you can use numbers inside the urls without problem i think. Would appreciate some testing from your side.

Comment: With the Id thing i think you just have to say it is a rule that a url only taking one id the parameter has to be :id

Comment: I am currently testing and encounter a few bugs, do you mind joining the chat ? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208187/discussion-between-dimitri-kopriwa-and-supporterino).

Comment: For instance, the last expression doesn't permit to have `/users/{id}` as a path, while it should be supported, as well as `/users/{id}.html`, not just `/users/{id}/view.html`