# How to validate URLs with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I validate URLs with custom regex in react-router-dom?

I tried the following approach but it didn't seem to work

```
<Route path="to/page/:path(regex)" component={MyPage}/>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It redirects to the Error page instead. I'm trying to check if :path is UUID or not. The regex is `/^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[5][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i`

Comment: That's a router parameter you are trying to call something on. By using just ":path", your component MyPage will get whatever is after that slash by let { path } = useParams();

Comment: @MalwareMoon Are you trying to say to have validation after this code let { path } = useParams();
and then check for the path if its matches the regex.

Comment: I'm using v5.3.0 of react-router-dom

Comment: What sort of path parameter validation are you trying to do/use? What is the regex? What exactly isn't working? We need to see an actual [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese Added the regex in my question. I'm trying to check if its UUID or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx that match react router path declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098019/regex-that-match-react-router-path-declaration)

Comment: @KillMe No sorry I misread the question. But according to everything what you have there is correct. Are you sure there is a mistake in this and not something else? Even when I tested it in sandbox it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "regex" that goes in the path isn't an *actual* REGEX object/literal, it's just a regex syntax *string* that the [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) package that `react-router-dom@5` can use and parse.

For your example you can remove the leading `"/^"` and trailing `"$/i"` and it should work for you.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/to/page/:path([0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[5][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12})"
  component={MyPage}
/>
```

[image: Edit how-to-validate-urls-with-react-router-dom]

Comment: Doesn't the /i mean, that you would need to have [0-9a-fA-F] instead of [0-9A-F]?

Comment: @MalwareMoon Perhaps. RRD path matching is already pretty case insensitive. Just tested now with lowercase link target in the URL and it still matched as expected. It might be an issue when using the [`sensitive`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/sensitive-bool) `Route` component prop though.